# Display Different Number of Groups in Highcharts Stacked Column Graph

Tags: graph, highcharts

I am trying to create a column highchart that is stacked and grouped, but I only want the last few x-values to have multiple groups/stacks.  The first x-values only have one group/stack.

To explain, I am charting historical values and then comparing optimistic and conservative forecast scenarios.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehulburd/uBuLu/4/).  A better way to do this?

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Thermal',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 5],
            stack: 'conservative',
            color:'blue'
        }, {
            name: 'PV',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 6],
            stack: 'conservative',
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            name: 'Thermal',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 10],
            stack: 'optimistic',
            color: 'blue',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'PV',
            data: [0,0,0, 12],
            stack: 'optimistic',
            color: 'red',
            showInLegend: false
        }]
```

Comment: Sure. You can specify per point what stack and group a data point is in.

Comment: I see that, but if I did that and left filled in 0's for the second stack's first x-values, the column would still be off center.  I want to know if there is a formal way to do this - either by splitting the chart or through a chart option.

Comment: I think you need to give us more info on your data itself. Can you provide a sample data set that illustrates the problem and/or set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: the problem with the jsFiddle is that the stack names are shared unless I create a third stack.

Comment: Okay, I see the issue now. There is gap. Setting point value to null did not work either. I am not sure.

Comment: did you ever end up finding a better solution (opposed to passing the 0's), i'm trying to achieve the same thing now.

Comment: @Stu I did and I just posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically highcharts is awesome and you can stack bars and give them relevant data on a point basis. I passed the following for my series array, with additional attrs to passs to the tooltip.  See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ehulburd/YZkUJ/):

```
 series:[
         {name:'Apples', color:'green', data:[{x:0, y:10, year: '2009', scenario: 'historic'}, {x:1, y:11,year: '2010',  scenario: 'historic'} ]}, 
         {name:'Oranges', color:'orange', data:[{x:0, y:2, year: '2009',  scenario:'historic'}, {x:1, y:5, year: '2010', scenario:'historic'}]},
         {name:'Apples',color:'green', data:[{x:1.75, y:12, year:'2011',scenario:'optimistic'}], showInLegend: false },
         {name:'Apples', color:'green',data:[{x:2.25, y:3,year:'2011',  scenario:'conservative'}], showInLegend: false },
         {name:'Oranges',color:'orange',  data:[{x:1.75, y:11, year:'2011',scenario:'optimistic'}], showInLegend: false},
         {name:'Oranges',color:'orange',  data:[{x:2.25, y:6, year:'2011',scenario:'conservative'}], showInLegend: false},
]
```

Comment: you should also combine the 3rd and 4th, as well as 5th and 6th, data objects.